# How to make a stretchable image view by scroll view

Tags: swift

I have a scroll view and an imageView at the top, I want to pin and make a stretchable image view but if I add this image view to the view the image won't disappear when the user scroll down the view and if I add the image to the scroll view this won't be pinned at the top when the user scroll down.
So how can I pin the image at the top and then when the user scroll down the image will disappear. 
Like that: http://blog.enabled.com.au/stretchy-layouts-on-ios/ but not with his framework.

```
class LocalsVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setNavBarSettings()

    scrollView.delegate = self

    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(imageView)
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let y = 300 - (scrollView.contentOffset.y + 300)
    let height = min(max(y, 60), 400)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: height)
}
```

Comment: Please share the code with what you have done so far, and I'm sure someone will be able to find out how to improve it.

Comment: The blog post you linked to gives all the information you need - just use layout anchors instead SnapKit

Answer (score 0):

Add the image to the scrollView and not to the view: `scrollView.addSubview(imageView)`.

Comment: but in this way the imageView won't be pinned at the top of the view.

Comment: It's either pinned to the top or scrolls down. I don't understand the question. maybe try to upload a picture of what you desire.